# PHP and MySQL URL-based permissions system, including wildcards

Tags: php, mysql, permissions

I'm currently developing a permissions system for a users database where each user can be a member of one or more permission groups. For example: my user `john_doe` is a member of the group "staff" and "accounting". New groups can be created so this part is dynamic, a list of groups is stored with the record for `john_doe`, which I can read to know if he's part of a group.

Now I'd like to handle access permissions with URLs, including wildcards. Also, I'd like it to be in a whitelist fashion but with exceptions based on other rules. For example: the group "staff" should be able to access URLs `http://example.com/dashboard/*` but not `http://example.com/dashboard/accounting` unless he/she is also part of the group "accounting". More generally, one should be able to access all URLs that match any of the wildcarded URLs of his/her groups, minus wildcarded URLs of groups in which he/she doesn't belong.

What is the best way of organizing data in the database so that it is easy and efficient to verify if a user can or cannot access an URL (fully defined, no wildcard) knowing the list of groups he/she belongs to?

The way I would do it would be to store a list of wildcarded URLs along with the record for the permission group, then do all the logic in PHP: get the list of groups for this user, get the list of whitelisted URLs from the groups he belongs to, get the list of blacklisted URLs from the groups he doesn't belong to, and match the requested URL against the whitelist, then the blacklist. Sounds pretty inefficient but I don't know if there is a better way.

Comment: Get list of groups. Write out a session variable for each group. Include a function or class that blocks or permits access based on the session variables and you're done.

Comment: hmm okay but then I need to sync those session variables with the status in the database. Maybe it's just simpler to get the full list of groups and their access rights from the database on every page display? But I can store the user's list of active groups in a session of course, I just need to log him out (I can do this because I'm using CodeIgniter sessions which are stored in a table) if a change of his groups has been made by, say, an admin.